# Build org.joda.time.DateTime with java.time.LocalDate and java.time.LocalTime or java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date, java-8, jodatime

So basically I have a DatePicker and TimePicker which will respectively give me a LocalDate and LocalTime. Now I want to use these values to make a org.joda.time.DateTime variable.

I'm not sure how to do that. I looked everywhere but I can't find a good answer to this all the answers I've found were for JPA which I'm not using.

Comment: not an answer but these days we only use the java LocalDate and LocalDateTime and skip the joda ones. The java ones are just a bit cleaner.

Comment: In which time zone do you want your Joda-Time `DateTime`? (I understand why you would not want a Joda-Time `LocalDateTime`.)

Comment: @OleV.V. CET or UTC +1

Comment: I could easily be tempted to convert to a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` first and then to `DateTime`. Get the `ZonedDateTime` from `yourLocalDate.atTime(yourLocalTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Tunis"))`. The the `DateTime` from `new DateTime(yourZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), DateTimeZone.forID("Africa/Tunis"))`. Advantages are you do most of the conversion work using the modern java.time API and you pass only two arguments to the `DateTime` constructor, greatly enhancing clarity over using a constructor with 6 or 8 arguments.

Comment: If you use a library check if it has a newer version

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Always a good idea. However in this case java.time replaced Joda-Time by Java 8, so Joda-Time mostly exists for folks who haven’t upgraded to Java 8 yet, so can’t be directly integrated with the java.time classes (`LocalDate` and `LocalTime`). So in this situation a newer version does not help us. If the OP can abandon Joda-Time completely and use java.time throughout, it will simplify her situation considerably, of course.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes.  The idea was that a newer version of the library explicitly targeting java.time would be a better long term solution.  These days joda is only for pre-Java8 legacy projects.

Comment: So to be clear, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, you meant a newer version of whatever API the OP (currently) needs the Joda-Time `DateTime` for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per official documentation https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html
you can use
**DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute, int millisOfSecond)**
Constructs an instance from datetime field values using ISOChronology in the default time zone.
The values for the constructor can be obtained from LocalDate and Localtime object
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: Good answer (+1). To get the milliOfSecond out of a `LocalTile` you need `yourLocalTime.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND)`.

Comment: Be very aware of time zones.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is very right. The mentioned constructor exists in a variant that additionally takes a `DateTimeZone` argument, where you can pass for example `DateTimeZone.forID("Africa/Tunis")`.